# Flash APIs for Android Platform

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, android-softkeyboard

My usage is very limited. All i need to do is to invoke the soft keyboard from within my flash application. Is there anything I can do, without using a textfield or any such editable controls, which will pop up the keyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need to have some sort of object that is interactive (that is, a textfield or something similar) to call up the on screen keyboard. This is probably because flash needs to set the focus for typing to that object. The object needs to be of type or of base type (somewhere in inheritance) InteractiveObject. You used the requestSoftKeyboard() method. Check it out:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#requestSoftKeyboard()

http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/03/everything-new-in-adobe-air-2-6.html

Comment: Note you could always just create a textInput, use it to call this method (don't add it to the stage) and then right after use the FocusManager to manually set the focus of the application somewhere else. This is flash, which means 99% of the time your solution is going to involve a hack. :)

Comment: requestSoftKeyboard() method is only available for FP version 10.2. any thing i can do for below 10.2 ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is a new method in the latest versions of flash player. :( The ONLY other hackish way might be to dispatch a mouse event from the focus target. This might trick the mobile VM into thinking the user has clicked on an object that requires they keyboard and automatically open it up.

Comment: For example, myTextField.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, true));

Comment: @Ascension well thanks for the answers they are a great help. And i think for now i will go with requestsoftkeyboard(); method, guess it wont be long before world moves to 10.2, right.