# How to kill the softkeyboard from flash player

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I needed a way to invoke softkeyboard in android platforms, and i got to know how to do it form here [Flash APIs for Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868058/flash-apis-for-android-platform). Now i need to kill the keyboard, basically there is a button which i want to use to toggle the keyboard. Flash has provided a way to invoke the keyboard but not to kill it.(never understood how they work). One more issue is that when i click the down button on softkeyboard which is located on bottom left of the screen, the Softkeyboard_Deactivate event is not fired. It seems its fired only when the focus shifts from one object to another.

So what should be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so it seems if you just set the "stage.focus = null" it will lower the keyboard. It came out of the blue to me to try this and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will work and this is a bit of a hack but on the hide button click you could set focus to an off screen textfield which has its needsSoftKeyboard property set to false.

I dont have an android phone so im unable to test that this works from here.

Comment: the problem is that there is no way of knowing when the hide button is clicked as softkeyboard events(activate and deactivate) are not fired. This might work when i use my button to toggle the softkeyboard. let me see if it does.

Comment: Yeah I was referring to your button. Is the keyboard also not closing when you press the close button on the actual keyboard too?

Comment: no no the hide button on softkeyboard is working fine but its not throwing the SoftkeyboardDeactivate event. so i dont know when to toggle my boolean variable. I only have one button which shows/hides the keyboard, so if the var is not set my button wont show the keyboard. But that is another issue, let me kill the keyboard first by tryin to set the focus to another object.

Comment: baah, it seems that just shifting the focus is not working, so i tried to dispatch a mouse click event to object on which i shifted the focus. I did this because after shifting the focus if i clicked on the object the keyboard deactivated. :???

Comment: damn, I cant think of anything else to try at the moment. I will keep thinking and get back to you if I come up with anything.

Comment: And there is a voila moment, just set the "stage.focus = null" and the keyboard automatically disappears. :)