# Get soft keyboard on iOS to show up in Pure AS3 mobile project (flex 4.5)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I have a Pure AS3 mobile project that I'm developing in Flex 4.5, and deploying on both Android and iOS.

I have a TLF textfield that is set to editable, and when I touch on it on Android the soft keyboard shows up as expected, without me having to explicitly tell it to show up.

BUT on iOS, when I touch on it, I get the text field's focus event firing, but the soft keyboard doesn't show up. Anyone know how to make this appear, so the user can enter in text?

Please tell me it is possible to enter text in a pure AS3 mobile app on iOS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect you should really do a thorough search on google or even stackoverflow, as this question has been posed already at least once. Anyway here is a question on the same issue I answered here:

[Flash APIs for Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868058/flash-apis-for-android-platform/5870658#5870658)

Basically it involves a new method in InteractiveObjects that manually invokes the system soft keyboard. Pretty basic stuff. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Agreed. My search wasn't very exhaustive. Thanks for your answer nonetheless!

Comment: That does not work in iOS. Look at the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#needsSoftKeyboard

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the soft keyboard on CLASSIC TEXT, you cannot use it on the new TLF (as of this post)...

Answer (score 1):

You can do... textfield.needsSoftKeyboard = true;

I know this works for Andriod haven't tried on iOS.