# AIR popup window with virtual keyboard(as3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, virtual

This is about kiosk contents(Full-Screen).

I'm trying to input some texts in the **'AIR popup-window'**(facebook login)
with virtual keyboard(as3.0).

I know the 'HTML loader class' can be a solution, But I think this is different case.

How can I make it? I really need your ideas!
Thank you for read this, and sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect you should really do a thorough search on google or even stackoverflow, as this question has been posed already at least once. Anyway here is a question on the same issue some one answered here:

[Flash APIs for Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868058/flash-apis-for-android-platform/5870658#5870658)

Basically it involves a new method in InteractiveObjects that manually invokes the system soft keyboard. Pretty basic stuff. Hope it helps! :)